# jsPDF PubSub Error Cannot read property 'widths' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'widths' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, jspdf

I have issue below is my error in browser console 
jsPDF PubSub Error Cannot read property 'widths' of undefined TypeError: Cannot read property 'widths' of undefined
    at jspdf.min.js:171
    at c (jspdf.min.js:171)

I am using node package - "jspdf": "^1.4.1" 
Please let me know , why issue come ?

Comment: Please provide your code here.